# Can't write to file in Fotran90

Tags: file, printing, fortran

I can't understand why my Fortran90 program does not write to file anymore. It used to work some hours ago. I haven't modified that part of the code, nor I have introduced some conditions by virtue of which it should not write to file . On the next line i have put a print command which writes on terminal the same values that should be written to file, and this works.

```
open(500, file='data.dat')
write(500,fmt='(E14.4,E14.4)') A,B   !this SHOULD be printed on unit 500
write(*, fmt='(E14.4,E14.4)') A,B   ! this is printed on terminal
```

I have tried to change unit, but nothing changes. I have tried to open a new file with a new name and writing onto it, also in other parts of the code, even at the beginning, just after variables declaration. This does not seem to work either. It is so frustrating, because everything worked properly previously. What could have happened?

Comment: You say what you expect to happen, but not what does happen.  Can you elaborate?  Also, can you give a [mcve] which exhibits the problem?  As it is I can only guess.  I can, though, ask: what happens if you put `action='write', position='rewind', status='replace'` in the `open` statement?

Comment: What happens when you try removing the format part? `write(500, *) A,  B`

Comment: As an aside: this post is an example of why you should always use a version control system and check in changes early and often. Being able to bisect changesets to isolate a bad edit has saved me countless hours and a lot of frustration. Without moralizing or being a jerk about it, please consider learning mercurial, git, RCS - any version control system you can wrap your head around. It pays off almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Using gfortran 5.3 under Linux and the following program (that is your code copy-pasted and the minimal boilerplate).

```
program hop
  implicit none

  double precision :: A, B

  A = 1
  B = 2

  open(500, file='data.dat')
  write(500,fmt='(E14.4,E14.4)') A,B   !this SHOULD be printed on unit 500
  write(*, fmt='(E14.4,E14.4)') A,B   ! this is printed on terminal

end program hop
```

outputs `0.1000E+01    0.2000E+01` in the terminal and the exact same content in the file `data.dat`.

Is the write instruction in a program that hangs? Not seeing output might be related to i/o buffering.

Is the behaviour changing if you add the line

```
flush(500)
```

after the write instruction?

Comment: Also, using the `iostat` and `iomsg` arguments to `open`, `write`, etc, should provide some clues if there's an intermittent or external problem (i.e. disk full, file permissions issues, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I have to write to file in a cycle. Now I open the file in the cycle having added position='append' and I close it at the end of the cycle.   Just like

```
program pro
implicit none
integer (kind=2) :: i, A, B
do i=1,10
A=i
b=i+1
open(500, file='file.dat', position='append')
write(500, *) A, B
close(500)
enddo
```

That seems to work now.

Comment: Why opening and closing in each iteration? Open it just once at the beginning.

Comment: the close does serve as a flush, in case you are trying to view the file in real time while the code is running.